# How can I check if all the elements of an ArrayList are same in java?

Tags: java

Suppose, there is an integer type ArrayList **arr**.

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new Arraylist<>(5);

arr.add(15);
arr.add(15);
arr.add(15);
```

So now,how can I check my ArrayList if all values are same or not?

Comment: check this article : https://www.baeldung.com/java-list-all-equal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Stream`s:

```
if (arr.stream().distinct().count() <= 1) {

}
```

Or a `Set`:

```
if (new HashSet<>(arr).size() <= 1) {

}
```

Both will work as long as all the elements of the `List` are equal according to the `equals()` method.

EDIT: I made a slight change to return `true` even if the `List` is empty, since you can argue all the elements are equal in an empty `List`.

Comment: I would prefer the first one.

Comment: @ManojBanik me too, but I added the second option in case a pre-Java 8 version is used.